# Easiest Wifi module/shield to interface with Arduino Fio?

Tags: arduino, wireless

This is my first time doing any arduino build, and I'm planning to build a digital hydrometer/thermometer for home brewing. I'd like to either run a simple webserver on the arduino or transmit the information to a small server that I'll be setting up. In order for it to fit into my fermentation vessels, the device needs to be less than 2 inches in diameter, although length is not too constraining. This limits me to the Arduino Nano or Fio and smaller modules. I'm thinking of going with the Fio, since the 3.3v output on the Nano isn't powered when running from external power. For Wifi on the Fio, I'm looking at either the XBee Wifi module or the WiFly GSX breakout board. Are there any advantages to one versus the other?

On a more general note, is the Fio a good choice for this project? I'll need to be pulling information from a temperature sensor (I haven't begun researching this yet, so any recommendation of favorite sensors/methods would be welcome) and [this liquid level sensor](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10221). The project will also need to be battery powered.

tl;dr - XBee Wifi module or WiFly GSX board for interfacing with the Fio?

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer but hopefully it'll be useful.

It looks like it hasn't yet been released but DIY Sandbox (diysandbox.com) is making an Arduino Mini with onboard WiFi and it's only 1.5" wide.  Look for their Platinum device here: http://diysandbox.com/our-products/arduino/platinum

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the PT board from DIY Sandbox ( http://www.diysandbox.com ) is on sale now.  I tested it out and its pretty cool that all of the functionalities of Arduino + WiFi is integrated in a board as small as this.

Here is there link:  http://diysandbox.com/our-products/platinum-arduino-mini-with-wifi

Answer (score 0):

[Yellow Jacket](http://ruggedcircuits.com/html/yellowjacket.html) is a great all in one Arduino and Wifi solution for less than $60